# How to rebase an interface default method with ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I'm trying to annotate a default method at runtime using `ByteBuddyAgent`. In order to keep the default implementation, I'm using a rebasing strategy, but I can't figure out how to intercept the new method with a call to the original one.

I tried using `MethodCall.invokeSuper()` and `MethodCall.invokeSelf().onDefault()`, but with both give me an `IllegalStateException`.

```
new ByteBuddy()
.subclass(MyInterface.class)
.method(isDeclaredBy(typeDescription).and(isDefaultMethod()))
    .intercept(MethodCall.invokeSelf().onDefault())
    .annotateMethod(AnnotationDescription.Builder
        .ofType(MyAnnotation.class).build())
.make()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE`. This way, Byte Buddy gets a chance to locate the actual super method which is the rebased method.

In your case, you would only invoke the same method recursively. Also, the `onDefault` configuration would attempt to invoke a default method on an interface implemented by `MyInterface`.